# How to get something like the last order per customer?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've written the following query but it takes a lot of time. I'm trying to fetch the latest records inserted in my `pm_data_records` table per each node. Nodes are stored in `pm_info` table, one row per node.

I wrote a query and I think it retrieves my intended data but it takes 15 secs.

Note that I have more than a million records.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 
    info.pm_detail_id,
    ... , 
    info.pm_min_pressure, 
    datas.`pm_detail_id`,
    ... , 
    MAX(pm_sent_time) 
FROM 
   `pm_data_records` as datas 
RIGHT JOIN pm_info as info 
   ON datas.pm_detail_id = info.pm_detail_id 
GROUP BY 
   info.pm_detail_id 
ORDER BY 
   info.pm_detail_id
```

tnx a lot

Comment: Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: @jarlh the group by is because i want the latest record of each node, not just the latest record stored in `pm_data_records`. tnx for the comments though ;)

Comment: Your current GROUP BY query isn't valid SQL, will raise an error on newer MySQL versions.

Answer (score -1):

Your query is not correct -- the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` clauses are inconsistent.  Here is a correct version:

```
SELECT i.*, dr.*
FROM pm_info i LEFT JOIN
     pm_data_records dr 
     ON i.pm_detail_id = dr.pm_detail_id AND
        dr.pm_sent_time = (SELECT MAX(dr2.pm_sent_time)
                           FROM pm_data_records dr2
                           WHERE dr2.pm_detail_id = dr.pm_detail_id
                        );
```

Now that you have a reasonable query, you can work on optimizing it.  This query wants an index on `pm_data_records(pm_detail_id, pm_sent_time)`.

Comment: somehow both queries are retrieving the same amount of data, but yours is taking more than 90 secs! I'm defiantly looking for one that takes a lot less time, can help me optimizing one of the queries ?

Comment: @arian.s . . . This query is *correct* SQL.  That is where you should start with optimizations.